# Take offs on a new trunk line

Tags: ducts

I recently had all new duct work put under the house because the old was severely undersized, (8x14) rectangular duct 50’ long with 17 take offs) with a 4 ton unit.
My question is the placement of take offs at the end of the trunk line, is there a minimum distance for spacing?  I am trying to reason with contractor who did the work but,  there are 6 take offs within 4 feet of end of trunk line, 2 sets are on exact opposite sides of each other, then the other two are crammed between these two, I wish I could draw it up but there is an 8” take off at end of run, with a 6” opposite it, then two 6” then 2 more 6” opposite each other.
“   6 I 8
I 6
I 6
6 I 6”
In this configuration where the I is the trunk line, 4’ from 6-8 to the 6-6 and the 8-6 are at the very end of trunk line maybe 2” in is this the correct way to run?

Comment: I'm thinking you need a drawing.

Comment: Hard to tell from the photo, but it looks like the main trunk is the same diameter throughout the run.  In general, you want the trunk diameter (or cross section) to reduce as you go down the run, away from the air handler, in order to keep the same pressure throughout the air distribution system.